# Counting words in a String in Python

Tags: python, string

I need to write a program that asks for a letter and also an input. I need to find the number of the words that contains that specific letter and also lists those words. So far i have been able to list the words that contain that specific letter however i can't find the amount of words that contain this specific letter.

So far my code is:

```
a = input("Letter: ")  
b = input("Input: ")  
a=a.lower() 
b=b.lower()  
c=b.count(a)
print(c)  
words = b.split()  
print(' '.join([word for word in words if a in word]))
```

And the output is this:

```
Letter: e 
Input: ee eeeee the 
8 
ee eeeee the
```

However, the answer should be 3 not 8 as only 3 words contain the letter 'e'.

So, can i get any help in fixing my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry if this is a stupid question but i only started coding last week.

Comment: looks like homework ;)... HINT: think again about what you have to count, and think about what b is in b.count(a)

Comment: It is for a coding competition. It is the first time that i have ever done coding.

Comment: well, if you print the words you can as well count them right?

Comment: Yeah, but i don't know how to count words in a string.

Comment: but you've got a list of words in your las line... so you have all words with an a in them in a list, so just check how long the list is no?

Comment: That is the problem. I don't know how to check how long the list is.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len

Comment: thank you for providing a link to this website. It has some really useful functions that might come in handy for later.

Comment: python documentation is really good, just make sure you select the correct version in left top corner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, except that you should count the number of elements in the list you create in the last line. This should work instead:

```
a = input("Letter: ")  
b = input("Input: ")  
a=a.lower() 
b=b.lower()  
words = [word for word in b.split() if a in word]  
print(len(words))
print(' '.join(words))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a ="ee eeeee the"

print sum("e" in x for x in a.split())
3
```

Split the words and check if `e` is in each word and use sum to get the total.

`b.count(a)` is counting every occurrence of the letter.

```
In [1]: a ="ee eeeee the"

In [2]: a.split()
Out[2]: ['ee', 'eeeee', 'the'] # splits into individual words
In [3]: sum("e" in x for x in a.split()) # e is in all three words so sum returns 3
Out[3]: 3
```

You can also change your code and use  `len()`

```
final_words = [word for word in words if a in word]
c = len(final_words)
print c
final  = (' '.join(final_words))
print final
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you currently wrote it, you are counting all occurences of the letter `e`. You just need to check if the word contains the letter, then move on to the next word.

```
>>> a = 'a'
>>> s = 'aaa bbb ccc ddd eaa faa abc'

>>> words = s.split()
>>> words
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eaa', 'faa', 'abc']

>>> len(filter(lambda i : a in i, words))
4
```

As a function

```
def wordCounter(letter, sentence):
    wordList = sentence.split()
    return len(filter(lambda word : letter in word, wordList))
```

Testing the function

```
>>> wordCounter(a, s)
4

>>> wordCounter('e', 'ee eeeee the')
3
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, i have only started coding last week so i don't really understand all these commands such as filter and lambda.

Answer (score 0):

```
found = [word for word in words if a in word]
num = len(found)

print num
print ' '.join(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
    `c=b.count(a)`
to something like
    `c = sum(a in word for word in b.split())`